# Transform colors given 2x2 color pair (in Photoshop)

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, colors

I would like to transform colors in the attached image (and other hundreds) defined by the following rule:

- 1) the lightest blue became the light green (exactly like as in the upper right color sample rectangle),
- 2) and the darkest blue became the dark green (exactly like as in the bottom right color sample)

[image]

I've tried to mod hue and lightness and can transform what satisfies 1) or 2) but not both at the same time.

Please note recreating the image with the 2 greens with gradient is not and option because I have many images with many details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting, what have you tried so far? The colour picker tool can do this!

Comment: As I wrote I've tried modify hue+lightness and can transform one blue to the one green or the other blue to other green. But I can not transform both to the same time. (Btw as far as I know the color picker tool picks colors and does not read our mind :-)

Comment: I'm lost - why does it have to be at the same time? I mean, can  you not create a macro (I think it's called an Action in Photoshop).. it's not at the same time, but will be so fast it will be very close!

Comment: Because if I do it in 2 steps, then the 2nd color change ruins the previous result. If you see the original blue part you can see it is not 2 discrete color instead a gradient. I would like to get the exact result and converted all the shades to get a result in which the darkest blue will be the darkest green and the lightest blue will be the lightest green.